# What is the best way to provide analytics data to users of an application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, redis

What is the best way to track pageviews, shares and other kinds of events on a website and provide the data to certain users of the app? For instance, let's say I have a blogging app and I want authors to be able to see how many times a specific post has been read or shared...

Should I use the Google Analytics API or should I roll my own solution using a key/value store db? Are there any other options out there? What's the best way to accomplish such a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics is probably the way to go. While it's certainly possible to roll your own, GA solves many issues you might not even think of, and its API is fairly straightforward.